# How to tell IntelliJ about javascript event properties so it stops warning about undefined props?

Tags: javascript, intellij-idea

IntelliJ seems to constantly complain about "Unresolved variable" for JavaScript.

For example, in

```
document.getElementById('myId').onclick = async event => {
    if (event.target.classList.contains...
```

it will underline `classList` with a warning "Unresolved variable classList"

classList is a [well defined property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList).  But an [EventTarget](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget) could in theory be other things.  Is there a "right" way to code or annotate it such that IntelliJ doesn't complain?

Comment: JSDoc comment describing `event.target`'s type should help here.

Comment: Isn't that built-in? Not sure where I would put that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The IDE has no idea what your target element is, and `EventTarget` interface doesn't have `classList` property. You need to explicitly tell the IDE the type of the HTMLElement which is your target. For example:

```
document.getElementById('myId').onclick = async event => {
  const target = /** Element */ event.target;
  if (target.classList.contains
```

Comment: This should probably be `@type {HTMLElement}`, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/21489264/5069530